Is there anyway to configure request level timout for JAX-RS WebClient?
I'm trying to configure request level timeout using JAX-RS WebClient, I don't want create different WebClient instance for every different path. Is there anyway to do that without changing WebClient instance itself?
Something like this:
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient;
public class testService{

    WebClient client;


 public void initClient(){

client= WebClient.create("localhost:8080");
}

public void firstRequest(){
 WebClient.fromClient(client).path("first").timeout(20).....
}


public void secondRequest(){
 WebClient.fromClient(client).path("second").timeout(10)....
}


}


you can use HTTPClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout method like the following
      public void firstRequest(){
            WebClient reqClient = WebClient.fromClient(client).path("first");
            ClientConfiguration config = WebClient.getConfig(reqClient);
            HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
            httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(2000L);
            config.getHttpConduit().setClient(httpClientPolicy);
    }


this method actually changing the main client instance too. So basically you always changing timeout with every request. In a multithreading application that may cause problems, because while one thread is changing the timeout other thread may start a request and timeout would not be set correctly in this case.
